# Why do the color profile/spaces of my PNG images change when processed with Perl's Image::Magick?

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I have encountered some quite puzzling behaviour with ImageMagick (using [PerlMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php): I open a PNG picture, resize it, and saves it.

All good, except that the resulting image colors' are slightly different.

- [Original image](https://imgur.com/a/WrMfS)
- [Processed image](https://imgur.com/a/yQQwE)

```perl
# Create the ImageMagick object.
my $magick = Image::Magick->new;

eval {
    $magick->BlobToImage( $image );
};

$magick->Scale( ... );

# ...and then save it.
```

However, if I manually set the image's color space to "RGB" right before I save it, the images are similar color-wise;

```
$magick->Colorspace( colorspace => 'RGB' );
```

Why is this?

**EDIT:** If I do exactly the same, except setting the color space manually, *but* convert to JPEG before saving, the colors becomes correct. Even more puzzling. :-/

Comment: @SinanÜnür: `Sample` gives the same result. ImageMagick version being used: ImageMagick 7.0.5-5 Q16 x86_64

Comment: toreau, you might have an excellent eye, because to me both look the same! Checking both with `identify -verbose` I also notice no difference other than the gamma chunk which is not present in the original one, and `cHRM` and `bKGD`. Gamma is 0.454545 in the original and 0.45455 in the new one. Colorspace is the same. Maybe our systems or viewing programs react to that differently. I'm on Mac OS btw

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Weird. They are definitely different for me, and I also tried to change the color profile in OSX to see if there were any "matching" profiles. To no luck; it's always different. Also, see my edit about converting to JPEG "fixes the problem."

Comment: Yes I've been flipping between then looking very closely but no difference to me. Interesting about the JPEG. The thing is, I don't see any relevant difference in metadata between the images either. You sure you get the same difference in the imgur samples? Sorry!

Comment: `$image` contains the image as read from disk (or downloaded via http). There's not a problem there, because if I just load the image in Image::Magick and save it, without doing anything with it, it's perfectly OK. (Also sorry for mixing you two...)

Comment: See also [Why does this PNG image display differently in Chrome & Firefox than in Safari and IE?](https://superuser.com/questions/579216/why-does-this-png-image-display-differently-in-chrome-firefox-than-in-safari-a) and [The Sad Story of PNG Gamma “Correction”](https://hsivonen.fi/png-gamma/).

Comment: Yes, also the imgur pictures are different for me. What color profile do you use on your Mac? That "Sad Story..." article was _extremely_ interesting, though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @toreau The file sizes are different, but the pixel RGB values are identical as shown in detail in answer. The difference in file sizes comes from the gAMA chunk included in the modified image. Also, I have a feeling you still do not realize that sidyll and I are different people.

Comment: I'm very aware of you two being different people now. Sorry about that. :) What I don't understand, though, is why ImageMagick _add_ this kind of data when I don't ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

When the image is saved in PNG format using `Image::Magick`, a [gAMA chunk](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html#C.gAMA) is added as can be seen by comparing the output of [`gm identify -verbose modified.png`](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/identify.html) with the output of `gm identify -verbose original.png` shows:

```
$ fc original.info modified.info
***** original.info
      Standard Deviation:      18869.16 (0.2879)
  Filesize: 613.0Ki
  Interlace: No
***** MODIFIED.INFO
      Standard Deviation:      18869.16 (0.2879)
  Gamma: 0.45455
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Filesize: 614.2Ki
  Interlace: No
*****
```

The RGB color ***values*** in the files are the same, but the saved gamma correction information in the second file causes it to be displayed slightly differently than the original. That is why converting the image to JPG "fixes" the problem: It removes the gamma correction information.

Looking at the [ImageMagick source code](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/f19d414d0ac4527544fef324969aa2a5d38b1027/MagickCore/image.c#L3661), the stripping is achieved using:

> ```
> SetImageArtifact(image,"png:exclude-chunk",
>      "bKGD,cHRM,EXIF,gAMA,iCCP,iTXt,sRGB,tEXt,zCCP,zTXt,date");
> ```

Therefore, I recommended the OP try:

```
 $magick->Set(option => "png:exclude-chunk=gAMA");
```

in his Perl program, and the OP reported it solved the problem.

Related information:

- [libpng docs](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter10.html#png.ch10.tbl.1)
- [Fixing PNG Gamma](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2006/12/01/fixing-png-gamma/)
- [The Sad Story of PNG Gamma “Correction”](https://hsivonen.fi/png-gamma/)
- [Why does this PNG image display differently in Chrome & Firefox than in Safari and IE?](https://superuser.com/questions/579216/why-does-this-png-image-display-differently-in-chrome-firefox-than-in-safari-a)

Comment: Great answer, much appreciated! However, it doesn't say much about "why" and "what to do"...? :)

Comment: `Strip` is not an option; it removes too much information that is important for colors, among other things.

Comment: `$magick->Set(option => "png:exclude-chunk=gAMA");` gives me the correct colors. But this still doesn't help me much; why does ImageMagick add this chunk? I never asked for it?